# Locating an AWS S3 physically in a private subnet (like RDS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, subnet

Similar to how an RDS instance requires you to pick the specific subnets (which can be in a VPC's private subnet), can AWS S3 stores also be physically located in a VPC's private subnet?

Comment: While you have a potentially useful answer below, you are potentially asking the wrong question.  Using the VPC endpoint routing feature allows you to access S3 from private addresses inside VPC without traversing a NAT instance, but S3 "stores" (buckets) are logical entities using distributed storage and are not "physically" in one place nor logically on one subnet like RDS.

Comment: Thats a very important point. My goal is just security, and I know I still think like a brick-and-mortar admin. I was hoping to find a way to bypass the data traveling out on the public internet...I.e. being locked into the VPC and traveling only between the S3 and the private server on the 10.0.x.x subnet...versus leaving the VPC and coming back in.

Comment: ["Traffic between your VPC and S3 buckets does not leave the Amazon network"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html) in that configuration, but it's not technically locked entirely in the VPC. The bucket itself remains as it was.  Access to the bucket from the Internet is still possible, if your bucket policy and/or IAM policies permit it, but the data transfer path is arguably more secure in this setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is actually a very recent feature of S3. You can now define endpoints with access policies in VPCs. See this blog post for more information:
[VPC Endpoint for Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to find. My searches never caught this page. Thanks so much! I can accept the answer, but can't upvote it yet :P